# How to compress video using AVFoundation in iOS

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, avfoundation

Is there are any compression technique in iPhone to compress video using AVfoundation. or any open source.

Regards,
Jeeva

Comment: A) your question doesn't have enough detail (what are you trying to do? is this being compressed for local storage or for transmitting over the network or?) and B) there's many different compression techniques for data. Have you ever Googled before?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Recording Avdio and Video using AVFoundation frame by frame](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8046102/recording-avdio-and-video-using-avfoundation-frame-by-frame)

Answer (score 7):

Try this :)

```
+ (void)convertVideoToLowQualityWithInputURL:(NSURL*)inputURL outputURL:(NSURL*)outputURL successHandler:(void (^)())successHandler failureHandler:(void (^)(NSError *))failureHandler
{
    if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtURL:outputURL]) [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtURL:outputURL error:nil];
    AVURLAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:inputURL options:nil];
    AVAssetExportSession *exportSession = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:asset presetName:AVAssetExportPresetLowQuality];
    exportSession.outputURL = outputURL;
    exportSession.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie;
    [exportSession exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler: ^(void) {
        if (exportSession.status == AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted)
        {
            successHandler();
        }
        else
        {
            NSError *error = [NSError errorWithDomain:domain code:code userInfo:userInfo]; 
            failureHandler(error); 
        }
     }];
}
```

Comment: i'm a little confused as to why that whole thing is one big failurehandler.

Comment: What do you mean, MrTristan?

Comment: absolutely nothing i guess. i'm sorry, the complex method signature confused me a bit. i thought that I was looking at a block on the end and all of the code here was part of that "failure handler block." a misinterpretation on my end. :-)

Comment: Hi, After using the above code also the file size remains the same for the video file before and after compression.

Comment: S K is correct. The number of bytes in NSData remain the same before and after this method.

Answer (score 1):

Here is best example provided by Apple for recording using AVFoundation

You can make settings (Dimension/ FPS/ BitRate) custom.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/RosyWriter/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011110

Hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is called `AVAssetWriter`. Search around for examples, it is too complicated to give a coherent piece of working code as an answer here.

Comment: "Here" is where people come for answers.

Comment: @mpemburn that's right, answers to "real questions"