# Compress video for sharing like Apple?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa, avfoundation

In the default photos app, Apple allows you to share videos to youtube, facebook,vimeo, etc.. I want to reproduce this function, but I record my videos in 1080p, so they are very large files. Apple solves this problem by compressing the video before uploading. I tried doing the same but failed miserably. Can anyone point me in the right direction? I found this question useful, but I can't understand why it doesn't work for me: [iPhone:Programmatically compressing recorded video to share?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5687341/iphoneprogrammatically-compressing-recorded-video-to-share).

Here is what I am trying:

```
- (void)convertVideoToLowQualityWithInputURL:(NSURL *)inputURL
                                   outputURL:(NSURL *)outputURL
                                     handler:(void (^)(AVAssetExportSession *))handler {
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtURL:outputURL error:nil];
    AVURLAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:inputURL options:nil];
    AVAssetExportSession *exportSession = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:asset presetName:AVAssetExportPresetLowQuality];
    exportSession.outputURL = outputURL;
    exportSession.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie;
    [exportSession exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^{

        switch ([exportSession status]) {

            case AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed:
                NSLog(@"Export failed: %@", [[exportSession error] localizedDescription]);

                break;

            case AVAssetExportSessionStatusCancelled:

                NSLog(@"Export canceled");

                break;

            default:

                break;
        }
    }];
}

-someMethod{

    NSURL *videoURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:self.currentVideoURL];

    NSArray *videoSplit = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",videoURL] componentsSeparatedByString: @"."];

    NSString *first = [videoSplit firstObject];
    NSString *output = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_Low_Qual.%@",first,[videoSplit objectAtIndex:1]];

    NSLog(@"VIDEO URL IS: %@",videoURL);
    NSLog(@"OUTPUT URL IS: %@",output);

    NSURL *outputURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:output];

    [self convertVideoToLowQualityWithInputURL:videoURL outputURL:outputURL handler: ^(AVAssetExportSession *exportSession)
     {
         if (exportSession.status == AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted) {
             printf("completed\n");
         }
         else {
             printf("error\n");
         }
     }];

}
```

However, it gives me 'Export failed: The operation could not be completed' every time. The video URL's are valid, so I don't know why it won't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Use AVAssetExportSession *exportSession = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:theAsset presetName:AVAssetExportPresetLowQuality];

Comment: Just tried that to no avail :(

Comment: Are you still getting export failed?

Comment: Print the NSError. Use AVAssetExportSession properties status and error.

Comment: That actually is the error. I'm doing `[[exportSession error] localizedDescription]`.

Comment: Try logging the .status throughout the methods

Comment: It gives me a 4, which is equal to `AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed`. Sorry, not very useful, I know.

Comment: Have you seen this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8851335/how-to-compress-video-using-avfoundation-in-ios

Comment: Yeah try using the [exportSession exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^(void) {
        if (exportSession.status == AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted) {
            successHandler();
        } else {
            NSError *error = [NSError errorWithDomain:domain code:code userInfo:userInfo]; 
            failureHandler(error); 
        }
     }];

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is the correct answer but when I changed my presetName to AVAssetExportPreset640X480, compression is working every time I run the code.