# Open camera in half portion of screen - iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, view, ios5, camera

I want to ask that , can I open iPhone camera in some limited portion on view?

I have implemented bar code reader concept in my app in which I am using camera.

Now, i want to open the camera in specific area on view.
Is it possible?
If yes than how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Search for `AVFoundation` framework in google search, and try to read AVFoundation programming guide from Apple.

This question might help you too,

[Recording Audio and Video using AVFoundation frame by frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8046102/recording-avdio-and-video-using-avfoundation-frame-by-frame)

Good luck!

**Tutorial :**

http://red-glasses.com/index.php/tutorials/ios4-take-photos-with-live-video-preview-using-avfoundation/